# How to get the value from the s3 input stream in java

Tags: java, string, amazon-s3, inputstream

I am trying to get value here :

```
  public char getTs() throws IOException {
   S3ObjectInputStream ts = null;
    int i;
    ts = (S3ObjectInputStream) s3Services.getResourceStream(fileURL.toString());
    while ((i = ts.read()) != -1) {
        c = (char) i;
        LOGGER.info("req time {} ", c);
    }
    return c;
}
```

The value I am getting is in bits, how to get the whole value at once?
Is it suitable to use an array?

```
My Output :req time 0
           req time 1
           req time -
           req time 0
           req time 1.... and so on
```

My expected output is :req time 01-01-2000 03:10:10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap the `S3ObjectInputStream` within an `InputStreamReader` and the `InputStreamReader` within a `BufferedInputStream`. That way you can read the object line by line:

```
var reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ts));
var line = reader.readLine();
```

Also check out [Apache Commons IO](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) which provide additional convenient streams and readers and utilities.

Comment: what is var here?

Comment: "Modern" Java.  You can just assign then to real types if you'd prefer.

Comment: You can declare variables using the var keyword since Java 10. [Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/var) could also be used to add that kind of syntactic sugar to your code.